# Oracle Forms select multi record into block

Tags: oracle, select, oracleforms

I want to select multi record into block using

```
SELECT  LEVEL, form_desc, form_NAME 
    FROM FORM_MAST 
    where form_id in ( select FORM_ID from  dhsuser.FORM_PRIVILEGE  where  PRIVILEGEID=1)-- :global.priv)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR form_ID = g_id
    START WITH g_id IS NULL;
```

or using this PROCEDURE  in Oracle Form

```
    PROCEDURE listm IS
l_lev number;
l_dec varchar2(30);
l_nam varchar2(100);

CURSOR mainlist is 
SELECT  LEVEL, form_desc, form_NAME 
FROM FORM_MAST 
where form_id in ( select FORM_ID from  dhsuser.FORM_PRIVILEGE  where  PRIVILEGEID=1)-- :global.priv)
CONNECT BY PRIOR form_ID = g_id
START WITH g_id IS NULL;

BEGIN

  for e_list in mainlist
  loop

    :bmain.level := e_list.level;
    :bmain.desc := e_list.form_desc;
    :bmain.fname := e_list.form_name;

end loop;
END;
```

The result should display more than one record 
as this pic
[image]

Problem is, when I run this procedure in Oracle Form it displays only the last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure loops through the result set from your query and assigns each record to the same single row in the :BMAIN block.  When the procedure finishes what you see is the last record fetched.

I think you just need to use NEXT_RECORD in the loop but I haven't got a Forms install I can test it on.  Sorry.